# PlotMarkers disappear when plotting exactly two polylines in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

Not sure if this is a MMA bug or me doing something wrong.
Consider the following function:

```
plotTrace[points_] :=
 ListPlot[points,
  Joined -> True,
  PlotMarkers -> Table[i, {i, Length@points}]]
```

now consider passing it values generated by RandomReal. Namely, consider

```
RandomReal[1, {nTraces, nPointsPerTrace, 2(*constant = nDimensions*)}].
```

If nTraces is 1, then PlotMarkers are displayed for all values of nPointsPerTrace that I tried:

```
Manipulate[
 plotTrace[RandomReal[1, {1, nPointsPerTrace, 2}]], 
 {nPointsPerTrace, 1, 20, 1}]
```

[image: plotting random points when nTraces == 1]

If nTraces is 3 or greater, then plot markers are displayed for all values of nPointsPerTrace that I tried

```
Manipulate[plotTrace[RandomReal[1, {nTraces, nPointsPerTrace, 2}]],
 {nTraces, 3, 20, 1}, {nPointsPerTrace, 1, 20, 1}]
```

[image: plotting random points when nTraces >= 3]

But if nTraces is exactly 2, I don't see plot markers, no matter the value of nPointsPerTrace:

```
Manipulate[plotTrace[RandomReal[1, {2, nPointsPerTrace, 2}]],
 {nPointsPerTrace, 1, 20, 1}]
```

[image: plotting random points when nTraces == 2]

Hints, clues, advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Interesting. I get the same thing on Mathematica 8.0.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's treating `PlotMarkers -> {1,2}` as a marker and size, instead of as two markers:

```
In[137]:= ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, PlotMarkers -> {1, 2}] // InputForm

Out[137]//InputForm=
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[{{1., 1.}, {2., 2.}, {3., 3.}, {1., 4.}, {2., 5.}, {3., 6.}, 
  {1., 1.}, {2., 2.}, {3., 3.}, {1., 4.}, {2., 5.}, {3., 6.}}, 
  {{{Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], Inset[Style[1, FontSize -> 2], 7], 
     Inset[Style[1, FontSize -> 2], 8], Inset[Style[1, FontSize -> 2], 9]}, 
    {Hue[0.9060679774997897, 0.6, 0.6], Inset[Style[1, FontSize -> 2], 10], 
     Inset[Style[1, FontSize -> 2], 11], Inset[Style[1, FontSize -> 2], 12]}, {}}}], 
 {AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1), Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 3.}, {0, 6.}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}}]
```

Comment: Yup, verified. A fix is `ListPlot[{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}},PlotMarkers->ToString/@{1,2}]`, and, in general, just to map ToString over the PlotMarkers calculated in my general function `PlotTrace`.  Thanks for a great answer.

Comment: Just verified it also works with `PlotMarkers->ToString/@Range[Length@points]` -- this definitely did not work in various version 7's, so this is an improvment.

Comment: @Reb `PlotMarkers->ToString/@Range[Length@points]` appears to work in version 7.0.1.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard -- Yes, I have mislaid the specific usage of Range in PlotMarkers that triggered a bug, but I got an acknowledgement from Wolfram that there was, indeed, a bug (they told me "use Table instead of Range"), so this is just something to keep an eye on until / if I can dredge out the old email.

Comment: `ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, PlotMarkers -> Transpose@List@{1, 2}]` (or `ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, PlotMarkers -> List /@ {1, 2}]`) also seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Things get even stranger when you try different things for `PlotMarkers`. The following does not display the plot markers, as in your examples above.

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {2, 10, 2}];
(* No markers *)
ListPlot[pts,
 Joined -> True,
 PlotMarkers -> {1, 2}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, when you change the `2` to `b`, it does:

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {2, 10, 2}];
(* Has markers *)
ListPlot[pts,
 Joined -> True,
 PlotMarkers -> {1, b}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you try to change the `1` to something, it doesn't work:

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {2, 10, 2}];
(* No markers *)
ListPlot[pts,
 Joined -> True,
 PlotMarkers -> {a, 2}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It does indeed sound like a bug, but I'm not sure if this is version dependent or some behavior that's not obvious.

Comment: Given that plot markers can be {marker,size} it seems that for option lists of length 2 Mma is not sure whether to treat this as {marker,marker} or {marker, size}. If the second element is an integer it seems to treat the list as {marker,size} by default. So PlotMarkers -> {a,2} is "invisible" because FontSize->2 is essentially invisible. If you want explicitly to have integer 2 as a label you could do PlotMarkers -> {a,"2"} or just add a third element PlotMarkers -> {a,2,stuff}.